# AWK :Extract columns from file: Rows have variable columns

Tags: gawk, awk

I have a text file in the following format. Each row has variable number of columns.

File:

```
gi|269201691|ref|YP_003280960.1| chromosomal replication initiation protein                                                            gi|57651109|ref|YP_184912.1| chromosomal replication initiation protein                                                                   %           1        0.0           2296      100.0
gi|269201692|ref|YP_003280961.1| DNA polymerase III subunit beta                                                                       gi|57651110|ref|YP_184913.1| DNA polymerase III subunit beta                                                                              %           1        0.0           1964      100.0
```

The resulting file should look like the following:

```
gi|269201691|ref|YP_003280960.1| gi|57651109|ref|YP_184912.1| % 1        0.0           2296      100.0
gi|269201694|ref|YP_003280963.1| gi|57651112|ref|YP_184915.1| % 1        0.0           1767      100.0
```

The code below helps find columns in each row with the pattern 'ref'.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /ref/) print $i }'
```

Any ideas on how to do the same?

Comment: You want multiple gi and refs on each output line? Has the text been wrapped here?

Comment: To avoid line wrapping, just indent your code with four spaces. But I see that your lines actually include two gi things. Ok, I will take that into account and update my answer.

Comment: The same as what? There are many reasons why you could be producing that output, tell us what it is you're keying off.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your newlines got mangled in your post, and that your input file actually has just one entry per line. In that case, I think this does what you want:

```
awk -F '[|%]' '{printf("%s|%d|%s|%s|",$1,$2,$3,$4);if($6)printf(" %%%s",$6);printf("\n")}'
```

Edit: Ok, in light of the new line numbers, what you want is probably this:

```
awk -F '[|%]' '{printf("gi|%d|ref|%s|gi|%d|ref|%s| %%%s\n",$2,$4,$6,$8,$10)}'
```

For your example, this produces the following output for me

```
gi|269201691|ref|YP_003280960.1|gi|57651109|ref|YP_184912.1| % 1 0.0 2296 100.0
gi|269201692|ref|YP_003280961.1|gi|57651110|ref|YP_184913.1| % 1 0.0 1964 100.0
```

This works by manually setting the field separator to be | or %. Hence, the variable number of words in the description is no longer a problem, and we can directly index the fields we want.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The code only prints the first column

Comment: If the code doesn't give the output I posted, then I have probably misunderstood the format your data is in. Could you post properly formatted input, indenting each line of input with four spaces? That will result in the sort of formatting you see in my answer, and notably, lines will not be broken.

Comment: If it works, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark. That shows others that you are no longer looking for answers for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*|.*|.*|.*|\)\(.*\)\(\S\+|.*|.*|.*|\)\2%/\1\3%/' file
```

If the input file has multiline records:

```
sed 'N;s/\n//;s/\(.*|.*|.*|.*|\)\(.*\)\(\S\+|.*|.*|.*|\)\2%/\1\3%/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ / gi$/) $i = " gi"; if (i = NF) sub(/.*%/," %",$i) }1' file.txt
```

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed 's/|[^|]* gi|/| gi|/; s/\(.*|\).*\(%.*\)/\1 \2/' file.txt
```

Results:

```
gi|269201691|ref|YP_003280960.1| gi|57651109|ref|YP_184912.1| % 1 0.0 2296 100.0
gi|269201692|ref|YP_003280961.1| gi|57651110|ref|YP_184913.1| % 1 0.0 1964 100.0
```